# apachectl does not automatically create /var/run/mod_fcgid

Tags: apache

[MacBook Pro 2014, Mac OS 10.13.3]

I have my apache install setup to use *mod_fcgid*.  However, when I restart my Mac, or after it restarts from sleeping, `/usr/sbin/apachectl` does not create */var/run/mod_fcgid*, which is needed along with correct permissions.

Since I cannot modify `/usr/sbin/apachectl`, due to SIP, so I'm wondering where can I add the necessary commands to create the folder?

Comment: Is the module loaded?

Comment: Yes.  To get it to work, I just need to create the folder and set permissions.

Comment: So, the answer is "No, it's not working."  `apachectl` shouldn't be modified to get modules loaded (this is why it's protected by SIP).  From a quick cursory search, this [Q/A ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303134/installing-php-fcgi-and-apache-with-worker-mpm-on-mac-osx-using-macport) seems to indicate the problem is with `mod_fcgid` and not with anything on Apache or macOS

Comment: The issue is that `apachectl` doesn't take into account that mod_fcgid needs the `/var/run/mod_fcgid` folder setup.  So, my question is; where is the best place, given that I can't edit `apachectl`, to put the required commands so that when Apache is started up, the folders are ready.

Comment: one could use configuration management (e.g. Ansible or whatnot) to ensure necessary directories and so forth exist before a command is run